# Makefile: Generate target from numeric sequence

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am interested in downloading yearly data from some location on the internet.
I have a python script `GetYearData.py` which does this, taking as a command-line argument the year and the output filename.
I'd like to run this script on several years of data at once; I want to use Make so that if I change the start or end year I don't have to re-download all the data.

I can do this for a single year with a very simple Makefile:

```
data/YearData_2000.txt  :  GetYearData.py
  python $< --year 2000 --outfile $@
```

However, I'd like to do this a loop (or similar construction) so that, for each year in a sequence in bash I'd say `YEARS=($(seq $(SYEAR) 1 $(EYEAR)))` -- I pass `--year $(Y)` to my script and generate an appropriate target for `--outfile`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SYEAR = 2000
EYEAR = 2017

YEARS := $(shell seq $(SYEAR) 1 $(EYEAR))

all: $(patsubst %,data/YearData_%.txt,$(YEARS))

data/YearData_%.txt : GetYearData.py
        python $< --year $* --outfile $@
```

You can override `SYEAR` and `EYEAR` on the make command line if you want.

Comment: I have added a interval function to [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which produces a up- or downcounting range: $(call interval , _start_ , _range_ [, _step_] )